# Azure Logic Apps - Prevent Recurrence Triggers from running automatically in VS Code

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am wondering if there is a way currently using the VS Code Extension to automatically disable all recurrence triggers without having to put "Workflows.yourworkflowname.FlowState" : "Disabled" in the local.settings.json for each workflow while also still being able to run those workflows manually.

I find it very hard to manage when working with a team as the local.settings.json cannot be shared between members. That is all I have tried as I am not aware of any other work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to achieve your requirement is to use PowerShell script. Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
$resourceGroupName = "<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>"
$LogicAppsDetails = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

$logicAppNames = $LogicAppsDetails.Name

for($I=0; $I -le $LogicAppsDetails.Count-1; $I++)
{
    $triggers = Get-AzLogicAppTrigger -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $logicAppNames[$I]
    if($triggers.Name -eq 'Recurrence'){
        Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $logicAppNames[$I] -State Enabled
    }
}
```

##### Results:

[image]

[image]